# Make Kinect V2 listen longer?

Tags: kinect, xbox-one

Kinect V2 for Xb1 (and I guess V1 for 360 too, but this question is mainly for One as I never used 360's much). Begins listening for commands after hearing "Xbox", but to string together commands is quite difficult as the Kinect stops listening after only a few seconds, and then you have to say "Xbox" again.

Is there a setting somewhere to make it so Kinect listens longer so you have time to read the new commands and choose or repeat commands (tv volume controls, "go back", switch snap view, etc)?

Comment: +1   I think this is a valid question here & a good question at that.   I will have to explore my XB1 tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tweeted at Xbox Support asking them this question as I couldn't find the setting.  This was their reply:

[image]

So currently, **there is no option for this.**